# calling jQuery on button click in web2py

Tags: jquery, web2py

I am having issues with calling this jquery on button click.
If i call the onclick() function when i declare the button it works.
However in this case i am not sure what i am doing wrong. Here is a snippet of my code. I am following a tutorial on web2py.

```
<table>
    <tr data-id="{{=post.id}}"><td><button data-direction="down">-</button></td>
        <td><span class="votes">{{=post.votes}}</span></td>
        <td><button data-direction="up">+</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

and the script is :

```
<script>
    function do_ajax_vote(t,direction) {
        alert('clicked');
    }
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('[data-direction=up').click(function(){do_ajax_vote(this,'up');});
        jQuery('[data-direction=down').click(function(){do_ajax_vote(this,'down');});
    });
```

Comment: `jQuery('[data-direction=up]')` and not `jQuery('[data-direction=up')`

Comment: tanks so much Shaunakde i totally missed that, so embarassing :)

Comment: Its totally okay. Difficult to debug in case of such problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correct attribute selector is : `$('[attributeName=NameValue]')`

Change

```
jQuery('[data-direction=up]')
```

Not

```
jQuery('[data-direction=up')
```